# Corona SDK and lldb

Tags: ios, coronasdk, lldb

Whether it possible to debug corona SDK application on iOS simulator?
I build a Corona SDK application for Xcode simulator and wrote next commands:

```
cd /Users/username/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/app-name.app/
lldb
(lldb) attach --name "app-name" --waitfor
```

Then I run app in simulator and I get the next message from lldb:

```
error: attach failed: process did not stop (no such process or permission problem?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in to the Mac remotely (`ssh` or whatever)?  You need to authorize debugging the first time you use the debugger.  It's easy to verify if your machine is set up to allow debugging:

```
% /usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity -status
Developer mode is currently enabled.
```

If it's not enabled, I think `sudo /usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity -enable` may do the trick.  If you're debugging locally, you should see a pop-up window asking you if you want to allow the debugging to happen.  But when logged in remotely, you won't see that pop-up of course.